# Securing XMLHttpRequest/AJAX from iterating through given parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, xmlhttprequest

Hello:) I am working on a project that requires to authenticate the user, not just via a normal login. I have certain information in my database (let's say projectnames) and I only want to show certain projects to certain users. The whole thing is already written in PHP, what I wanted to do now is to use `AJAX/XMLHTTPREQUESTS` from `JS`. The PHP file is taking the value of `uid` and returns then a json, that contains the information (in this case, projectnames of projects the user is working on). Yet I have it written like this:

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var uid = 1 //for testing
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        }
    };

    req.open("GET", "getprojects.php?uid=" + uid);
    req.send();
```

Basically this works great, and the PHP is also working. The problem I have now, is that someone could simply bruteforce it's way into my system by iterating through the UserIDs. My question now is how I could secure my code, so that not everyone can easily iterate through all the `uid`'s.

If you need more info, just tell.

Thanks already :)

Comment: What are you using to authenticate the user in the first place? Is there some secret cookie sent to the browser for their specific authenticate session or something similar? If so, could you check that against the request user id before returning the data?

Comment: Didn't think of that, great idea! Yes I have a Cookie placed in the users Browser which contains a Session Hash which I can use to authenticate the user :) Thank you!:)

Comment: No worries! ^^

You could even use that session instead of passing in a separate uid in the ajax GET.